# Is Azure Blob storage transactional?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

As the title states is Azure Blob Storage transactional?  I have a two scenarios:

1) I need to insert/modify two files. They need to be all or nothing so if one fails, none get inserted/updated.

2) When updating how is contention handled? Lets say I have file.txt. Two users at the same time want to update the content of that file. What happens in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If transaction context is what you are looking for, I don't think Azure Blob Storage supports it in nature. And it is common for most of the cloud storage.

We can confirm by looking at the API, there is no transaction context... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179377.aspx

For concurrency, there is a detail blog post explain how it work, please refer to below link for details.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Enjoy :)

Comment: @user2924127 you can take a snapshot of blob 1 before you overwrite it. Then if blob 2 failed to update you could restore to the snapshot of blob 1. But that would all be code you write. For info on snapshots see http://justazure.com/azure-blob-storage-part-7-snapshots/